# Action angle variables and Action

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, action

Action given by principle of least action ($S$) and action variable given by action angle variable theory ($J$) are same?

Answer (score 4):

In the ways these two notions are used, they are completely different things. However, I think their names share the common word *action* because conceptually they share a common underlying concept. But they are still different.

The common framework of both action and action-angle variables is the Hamiltonian formalism.

**Actions.** *Good for deriving equations of motion.* Let us have a Hamiltonain system with a Hamiltonian function $H= H(q, p)$, where 
$q = (q^1, ... ,q^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p = (p_1, ... ,p_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Then the dynamics of the system is determined by the solutions to the system of $2n$ differential equations
\begin{align}
&\frac{dq^k}{dt} \, = \, \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k}\big( q, p\big)\\
&\frac{dp^k}{dt} \, = \, -\, \frac{\partial H}{\partial q^k}\big( q, p\big)\\
& \text{ for } k = 1, ..., n
\end{align} 
Now, the action $S[\gamma]$ associated with the Hamiltonain $H(q, p)$ is a function, or rather a *functional*, whose

**1.** Input variables are functions $\gamma(t) = \big(q^1(t), ..., q^n(t), p_1(t), ...., p_n(t) \big)$ describing curves in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with the property that $q(t_1) = q_1$ and $q(t_2) = q_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are fixed ($t_1$ and $t_2$ are fixed and $q_1$ and $q_2$ are fixed);

**2.** The output is a number. The rule according to which the output is calculated is
$$S_H[\gamma] \, = \, \int_{ \gamma } \, \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\, p_k \, dq^k \, -\, H(p, q)\, dt  \right) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\, p_k(t) \, \frac{d q^k}{dt}(t) \, -\, H\big(p(t), q(t)\big)\,  \right)  dt$$

At the same time, the solutions of the system above coincide with the stationary curves (i.e. the critical curves) of the action $S_H[\gamma]$, a fact which is called the principle of stationary action 
$$\delta S_H[\gamma] = 0$$ It is well known that the solutions of the Hamilton's equations, which we said are the same as the stationary curves of the action, conserve the Hamiltonain function $H$, i.e. $$H\big(\gamma(t)\big) = H\big(q(t), p(t)\big) \equiv \text{constant}$$ 
An equivalent way of arriving at the principle of stationary action is by calculating the action 
$$S[\gamma] \, = \, \int_{ \gamma } \, \sum_{k=1}^{n}\, p_k \, dq^k  = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\, p_k(t) \, \frac{d q^k}{dt}(t)   \right)  dt$$
for all curves $\gamma(t) = \big(q^1(t), ..., q^n(t), p_1(t), ...., p_n(t) \big)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with the properties that

*-* $H\big(\gamma(t)\big) = H\big(q(t), p(t)\big) = c$ and

*-* $q(t_1) = q_1$ and $q(t_2) = q_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are fixed;

Then, the Hamilton's equations are equivalent to the restricted principle of stationary action
$$\delta S[\gamma] =0 \text{ under the restriction that } H(\gamma) = \text{const}$$

**Action-angle variables.** *Good for simplifying Hamiltonian systems.* Now in some cases, the Hamiltonain system of differential equations with function $H(q, p) = H_1(q, p)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ possesses a full set of conservation laws, in the form of $n$ Hamiltonian functions $$H_1(q, p), \, H_2(q, p), \, ..., \, H_n(q, p)$$ with the properties that 
$$\text{the differentials } dH_1(q, p), ..., dH_n(q, p) \text{ are linearly independent for all points }(q,p)$$
$$\{H_i, H_j\} = 0 \text{ for all } i,j = 1, ..., n$$
The latter property includes the fact that the solutions $\gamma(t)$ of the Hamiltonian equations of $H = H_1$ conserve all the functions, i.e. $H_j\big(\gamma(r)\big) = c_j$ for all $j=1, ..., n$. A system with these properties is called *integrable*.

Integrability allows us to find a set of new variables, such that when we change the variables $(q,p)$ to the new ones, the original Hamilton's equations simplify drastically. These variables are called the *action-angle variables*.

**Action variables.** First, for a set of $n$ constants $c = \big(c_1, ..., c_n \big) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define the set
$$M_c = \big\{ (q, p) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n} \, | \, H_1(q, p) = c_1, ..., H_n(q, p) = c_n\big\}$$ Then, $M_c$ is a smooth embedded Lagrangian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n
$ and if it is compact, it is an $n-$dimensional torus. On this torus, one can choose a set of $n$ simple closed loops $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_n$, generating its fundamental group. The exact shape and choice of the loops is irrelevant, all that matters is the that the loops are chosen to cover all $n$ transverse directions of the torus. Thanks to that, we can derive the new quantities
$$I_j = I_j(q, p) = \int_{\sigma_j} \sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k dq^k$$  By varying the points $(q,p)$ we select different tori $M_c$ for different $c_k = H_k(q,p)$ and thus the set of all these new quantities $$I_j = I_j(q, p)$$ becomes a set of $n$ new variables smoothly depending on the old variables $(q, p)$.

The name *action variables* comes from the fact that we are constructing the variables $I_j$ by applying the action 
$$S[\sigma_j] =\int_{\sigma_j} \sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k dq^k$$ under the conditions that 
$\sigma_j$ are loops that satisfy the stronger restrictions $H_1(\sigma_j) = c_1, ..., H_n(\sigma_j) = c_n$. This is a special case of the action from the first part of the discussion. Hence the name.

**Angle variables.** To change the variables completely and at the same time keep the Hamiltonain (so called canonical) structure of the equations of motion, we need a set of $n$ extra variables $\theta^1, ..., \theta^n$ which completes the set of action variables so that the new extra variables, called *angle variables*, are the conjugate variables to the action variables, i.e.
$$\{I_j, \theta^k\} = \delta_{j}^{k}, \,\, \{I_j, I_k\} = \{\theta^j, \theta^k\} = 0$$ This can be done.

Now we have a new set of variables $I_j = I_j(q, p)$ and $\theta^k = \theta^k(q, p)$ for $j, k = 1,..., n$ written as functions of the old variables $(q,p)$. The formulas can be inverted and $H(q, p) = \tilde{H}(I) = \tilde{H}(I_1,...,I_n)$. Consequently, the old system 
\begin{align}
&\frac{dq^k}{dt} \, = \, \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k}\big( q, p\big)\\
&\frac{dp^k}{dt} \, = \, -\, \frac{\partial H}{\partial q^k}\big( q, p\big)\\
& \text{ for } k = 1, ..., n
\end{align} can be written in the new action-angle variables as the simplified system
\begin{align}
&\frac{dI_k}{dt} \, = \, 0\\
&\frac{d\theta^k}{dt} \, = \, -\, \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial I_k}\big( I_1, ..., I_n\big)\\
& \text{ for } k = 1, ..., n
\end{align} with Hamiltonain function $\tilde{H}$. The latter system is easy to solve, so the solutions look like
\begin{align}
&I_k(t) = I_k^{0} \\
&\theta^k(t) = \theta_0^k - \, \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial I_k}\big( I_1^0, ..., I_n^0\big)\,t
& \text{ for } k=1, ..., n
\end{align}

Comment: What's your conclusion ? @ Futurologist

Comment: @robin What do you think? What did you gather form reading my post?